# video div not rendering correctly in firefox but renders fine in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video

I've got a project I'm working on and I am stumped. I've got a video that is not positioned right in firefox, but in chrome it is perfect. Here is the [Firefox version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlzrR.png) And here is the [Chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwe2U.png)
I'm not sure why they are rendering differently.
Here is a code snippet from that section of the html template:

```
<div ui-view>
    <div ng-controller="mainController" class="container">
        <div class="main_page">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <video autoplay playsinline muted loop>
                    <source src="vid/peer2package_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <h1>Peer2Package</h1>
                <p>Earn money for driving your car!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="logo_section">
                <div class="logos">
                    <div id="buy" class="front_logo"><img src="img/buy.svg">
                        <p>BUY</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sell" class="front_logo"><img src="img/sell.svg">
                        <p>SELL</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="deliver" class="front_logo"><img src="img/deliver.svg">
                        <p>DELIVER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="buy_things" class="main_section">
                <div class="column_one logo"><img src="img/buy.svg">
                    <p>BUY</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column_two text">
                    <p> Buy things and get them sent directly to you!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sell_things" class="main_section">
                <div class="column_one text">
                    <p> Sell things and no more customers complaining about the wait time!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column_two logo"><img src="img/sell.svg">
                    <p>SELL </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="deliver_things" class="main_section">
                <div class="column_one logo"><img src="img/deliver.svg">
                    <p>DELIVER</p>
                </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

div.main_page {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.jumbotron {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #1c283b;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  z-index: 9980;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

div.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.9em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -5px;
  z-index: 9987;
}

div.jumbotron p {
  margin-top: 90px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  z-index: 9988;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add the rendered code, with this code we can't help you. Add the rendered HTML and CSS code and all will be fine.

Comment: Sure, I've changed the jade to the rendered html.